# Hide Join if string.IsNullOrEmpty using Linq

Tags: linq

I got this linq query which searches for selected values in my database using dropdowns.

Is there a way to hide the "join" in the linq query if the ddlCategory is null? I want this because the result of the search shows duplicated-rows because my documents can have many Categories.?? hope you understand what i mean.. Can anyone help??

```
var documents = from d in data.tblDocuments

            join sc in data.tblSubCategories on d.DocId equals sc.DocId
            orderby d.Docyear descending 

            where
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(person) || d.DocPerson.Equals(person)) &&
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(year) || d.Docyear.Equals(year)) &&
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(law) || d.DocLaw.Equals(law)) &&
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(court) || d.DocCourt.Equals(court)) &&
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(category) || sc.CategoryId.Equals(category)) &&
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(casenr) || d.DocNr.Equals(casenr))

            select d;
```

Comment: You also has filtering by `sc` here

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda syntax:

```
var query = data.tblDocuments;

if (condition) // conditionally add join
   query = query.Join(data.tblSubCategories.Where(sc => sc.CategoryId == category), 
                      d => d.DocId, sc => sc.DocId, (d,sc) => d);

// continue to compose query
query = query.OrderByDescending(d => d.Docyear)
             .Where(d => ...);
```

BTW you can compose filtering based on conditions:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(person))
    query = query.Where(d => d.DocPerson == person);
```